# MODBUS TCP server with CISCO C-9300

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

I am planning to use the MODBUS TCP Server with the C9300 switches. Yet, I found the following guide:
CIP and MODBUS Configuration Guide, Cisco Catalyst IE3x00 and IE3100 Rugged, IE3400 Heavy Duty, and ESS3300 Series Switches - MODBUS [Cisco Catalyst IE3200 Rugged Series] - Cisco

but it is not applicable to the model I have (C-9300). Does the C-9300 support the MODBUS TCP server? if yes, could you please provide us with the guide.

Thank you.